# Which algorithms are used to locate objects in a 3d space?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, computer-vision, algorithm-request

I can see mobile apps that can locate a 3D object on a surface with a mobile camera and you can turn around that object.

What is the name of the algorithm(s) that is used for that purpose? Or, is there AI in these algorithms? Are they use plane detection? After detection, which algorithm do they use to locate the objects?

It seems like a Computer Vision problem, but I do not know the title.

[image]

Comment: Hello. Can you please provide the name of the apps that do this?

Comment: 3D Object Recognition (https://paperswithcode.com/task/3d-object-recognition) or 3D Object Detection (https://paperswithcode.com/task/3d-object-detection) is probably what you're looking for.